# SharePoint Online: Monthly Calendar View

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar

Is there a way to `shade` or `hide` any blocks that are part of the previous or next month?  Or way to include the `month` name next to the number? For example: Tuesday 1 should say May 1, and Friday 1 should say June 1?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OOTB view settings does not give us the option to trim the calendar to make it show only a particular month.

Using the F12 developer tools, we can know SharePoint uses “.ms-acal-outday” class for the blocks of the previous and next month days.
[image]

So we can use the following CSS to change the block style:

```
<style>
.ms-acal-outday{background-color:grey;}
</style>
```

[image]

However, the days and items are in different row. Check the following screenshots.

[image]

There is no class defined for days, so that we cannot use CSS selector to get the elements. It is difficult to identify which day need to be hidden.

You may need to do some coding to build your own calendar to achieve this functionality you’re looking for.